# Алгоритм заливки

Tags: android, bitmap, graphics

Вот составил такой алгоритм:

```
 private Bitmap fill(int x, int y, int color, Bitmap bitmap){

    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();

    int color2 = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

    if(color==color2||convertColorRGB(color)==color2){
        return bitmap;
    }

    boolean flagDown = true;
    boolean flagUp = true;

    ArrayList<int[]>stack = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    ArrayList<int[]>stackTemp = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    stackTemp.add(new int[]{x,y});
    stack.addAll(stackTemp);

    while (!stackTemp.isEmpty()){

        stack.clear();
        stack.addAll(stackTemp);
        stackTemp.clear();

        for(int[]point:stack) {

            flagDown = true;
            flagUp = true;

            while (point[0] > 0 && bitmap.getPixel(point[0], point[1])==color2) {
                point[0]--;
            }
            point[0]++;

            while (point[0] < w-1 &&bitmap.getPixel(point[0], point[1])==color2) {

                bitmap.setPixel(point[0], point[1], color);

                if (flagDown && point[1]<h-1 && bitmap.getPixel(point[0],point[1] + 1) ==color2) {
                    stackTemp.add(new int[]{point[0], point[1] + 1});
                    flagDown = false;
                } else if (!flagDown && point[1]<h && bitmap.getPixel(point[0], point[1] + 1) !=color2) {
                    flagDown = true;
                }

                if (flagUp && point[1]>0 && bitmap.getPixel(point[0], point[1] - 1)==color2) {
                    stackTemp.add(new int[]{point[0], point[1] - 1});
                    flagUp = false;
                } else if (!flagUp && point[1]>0 && bitmap.getPixel(point[0], point[1] - 1) !=color2) {
                    flagUp = true;
                }

                point[0]++;
            }

        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Здесь идет закрашивание по "полю". То есть закрашивает те пикселя цвет которых совпадает с пикселем клика. Почему то пропускает пиксели у границ области. При использовании этого алгоритма заливки по цвету границы, то есть закрашивает всю область очерченную определенным цветом, таких пропусков нету.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Два варианта, или убрать сглаживание линии или улучшить сам алгоритм.

Comment: Точно, убрал сглаживание и все заработало адекватно. Спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Дело в том что у Вас 4-х связный алгоритм заливки. Из-за этого пиксели которые находятся на диагоналях могут не попасть в проверку. Добавьте ещё диагональные пиксели.

Comment: Этот алгоритм не пропускает угловые пиксели.Так как каждая строка проверяется от начала и до конца. Я в список заносил и крайние пиксели, после чего их перепроверял, а так же пиксели вокруг, все восемь. Ничего не помогало, как оказалось все дело в сглаживании Paint. И в принципе меня это устроило, дальше ковырять алгоритм не стал.